# Casting interface with generic parameter implemented by class without generic parameter

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I have two interfaces,

```
public interface IDocument<SegType> where SegType : ISegment
```

and

```
public interface ISegment
```

Basically, I want to enforce that each class that implements `IDocument` is composed of one type of `ISegment`, and that people using these classes never need to know about which type of `ISegment` their class uses internally.

I then created a class that implements `IDocument<SegType> where SegType : ISegment` :

```
public class MyDocument : IDocument<MySegment>
```

and the corresponding `MySegment` :

```
public class FffSegment : ISegment
```

All of this compiles and works just as I expect it to when I specify `MyDocument` as the type.  Why can I not implicitly cast an instance of `MyDocument` to be of type `IDocument<Isegment>`?  When I try the line:

```
IDocument<ISegment> doc = new MyDocument();
```

I get the error

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'MyDocument' to 'IDocument<ISegment>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

But when I cast it, it just comes back null.  If I change it to:

```
IDocument<MySegment> doc = new MyDocument();
```

it works, as it does when I change the class definition to

```
public class MyDocument : IDocument<ISegment>
```

Why can I not force a specific type that implements ISegment for that implementation of IDocument?  I want to re-use this code for different types of `IDocument` and `ISegment` and maybe some day some implementations of `IDocument` will allow for multiple types of `ISegment` but `MyDocument` should be restricted against this kind of behavior.  How can I enforce these requirements but still write code that is generic enough to be re-used in the future?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get into the nastiness of co-and-contra variance:

```
public interface IDocument<out SegType> where SegType : ISegment
{}
```

I think that should make your example compile now...

Here's some reading material:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)

Comment: Thank you.  This is exactly what I needed.  That first msdn blog post link is especially interesting, and I think I'll have to read up on the other two as well.  I should note that I had to make another minor change.  `IDocument` had a return value on a method of `IList<SegType> but apparently `IList` is not covariant.  `IEnumerable` is, so I changed it to that.  Figured that out from this SO question:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/7416775/761590

Answer (score 0):

Because `IDocument<MySegment>` cannot cast directly to an `IDocument<ISegment>`.  If it could, you could do this:

```
IDocument<ISegment> doc1 = new IDocument<MySegment>;
doc1.Add(new MyOtherSegment());   // invalid
```

(Assuming `IDocument<T>` has an `Add(T newSegment)` method)

Take a long look at your design and decide if generics are really necessary or if just using `ISegment` within `IDocument` is sufficient.